# Bottom of JScrollPane is cut off

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am trying to create a simple email client and the bottom of the body is being cut-off. If I add a horizontal scroll bar, it does not appear, and the bottom of the Vertical scroll bar does not appear either.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
   import java.awt.Font;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
   import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
   import javax.swing.JTextArea;
   import javax.swing.JTextField;
   import javax.swing.UIManager;


   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public class gui extends JFrame{

gui(String title, int x, int y){

    super(title);
    setSize(x,y);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

}

public void addElements(){

    Font size30 = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 30);

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();

    //--- User Info ---//

    JPanel userInfo = new JPanel();

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
    JTextField userField = new JTextField(12);
    userInfo.add(userLabel);
    userInfo.add(userField);

    JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
    JTextField passField = new JTextField(10);
    userInfo.add(passLabel);
    userInfo.add(passField);

    JLabel serverLabel = new JLabel("Mail Server: ");
    JTextField serverField = new JTextField(10);
    userInfo.add(serverLabel);
    userInfo.add(serverField);

    JLabel portLabel = new JLabel("Server Port: ");
    JTextField portField = new JTextField(3);
    userInfo.add(portLabel);
    userInfo.add(portField);

    //--- To: CC: and Subject Fields ---//

    JPanel msgInfo = new JPanel();

    JLabel toLabel = new JLabel("To: ");
    JTextField toField = new JTextField(30);
    msgInfo.add(toLabel);
    msgInfo.add(toField);

    JLabel subLabel = new JLabel("Subject: ");
    JTextField subField = new JTextField(30);
    msgInfo.add(subLabel);
    msgInfo.add(subField);

    //--- Body ---//

    JPanel bodyPnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));

    JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel("Body");
    bodyLabel.setFont(size30);

    JTextArea bodyField = new JTextArea(30,70);
    bodyField.setLineWrap(true);
    bodyField.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JScrollPane bodyScroll = new JScrollPane(bodyField);

    bodyScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    bodyScroll.setBounds(getX(), getY(), bodyField.getWidth(), bodyField.getHeight());

    bodyPnl.add("South",bodyScroll);

    pnl.add(userInfo);
    pnl.add(msgInfo);
    pnl.add(bodyLabel);
    pnl.add(bodyScroll);

    contentPane.add("North", pnl);

    setVisible(true);

}

}
```

In my main class I am just creating a new gui and then calling the addElements() function.

Comment: `pnl` is using a `FlowLayout`, which doesn't "wrap" well, I'd consider using a different layout manager

Comment: Your scrollbar is not being shown because your textarea is empty and your scrollbar is set to 'as needed'. Try using `JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`

Comment: @error that is not the problem, the problem is that the bottom of the scroll bar is cut-off. At the bottom there is no arrow that you can press to make the scroll bar come down slowly

Comment: Ahh, I see. Like MadProgrammer said, it could be due to the layout manager. It could also be due to setting the JScrollPane to the height of the JTextArea. When you pass a Component into a JScrollPanes constructor, it should automatically compensate for size. Instead of setting the bounds (x, y, width, height) try just setting the location (x, y) of the JScrollPane.

Comment: Exactly, you should be setting **no** bounds of anything. Let the appropriate layout managers do this work for you.

Comment: what Layout Manager would you suggest I use to get a similar looking gui?

Comment: Also `pack()` the frame (after adding components), instead of `setSize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FlowLayout` doesn't "wrap" well.  Consider a different layout, `GridBagLayout` for example...

Also, stop "trying" to force a size onto your UI, you don't have enough control over the factors which affect sizing to do this.

Instead, rely on the layout managers and API functionality.  For example, instead of calling `setSize` on your frame, call `pack`...I would have posted soon, but it took me this long to find that call...I was scratching my head wondering why the UI wouldn't layout the way I expected...

[image: Form]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Test frame = new Test("Testing", 400, 400);
            }
        });
    }

    Test(String title, int x, int y) {

        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addElements();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
//        setResizable(false);

    }

    public void addElements() {

        Font size30 = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 30);

        //--- User Info ---//
        JPanel userInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 4, 2);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
        JTextField userField = new JTextField(12);
        userInfo.add(userLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        userInfo.add(userField, gbc);

        JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
        JTextField passField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx++;
        userInfo.add(passLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        userInfo.add(passField, gbc);

        JLabel serverLabel = new JLabel("Mail Server: ");
        JTextField serverField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx++;
        userInfo.add(serverLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        userInfo.add(serverField, gbc);

        JLabel portLabel = new JLabel("Server Port: ");
        JTextField portField = new JTextField(3);
        gbc.gridx++;
        userInfo.add(portLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        userInfo.add(portField, gbc);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 4, 2);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        //--- To: CC: and Subject Fields ---//
        JPanel msgInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel toLabel = new JLabel("To: ");
        JTextField toField = new JTextField(30);
        msgInfo.add(toLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        msgInfo.add(toField, gbc);

        JLabel subLabel = new JLabel("Subject: ");
        JTextField subField = new JTextField(30);
        gbc.gridx++;
        msgInfo.add(subLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        msgInfo.add(subField, gbc);

        //--- Body ---//
//        JPanel bodyPnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 4, 2);
//        gbc.gridx = 0;
//        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel("Body");
        bodyLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        bodyLabel.setFont(size30);

        JTextArea bodyField = new JTextArea(30, 70);
        bodyField.setLineWrap(true);
        bodyField.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JScrollPane bodyScroll = new JScrollPane(bodyField);

        bodyScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
//        bodyScroll.setBounds(getX(), getY(), bodyField.getWidth(), bodyField.getHeight());

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        add(userInfo, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(msgInfo, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 4, 10);
        add(bodyLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 10, 10, 10);
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(bodyScroll, gbc);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of FlowLayout Manager is being used. I have solved your problem with a different layout manager.
Before posting the solution here are some tips that you should follow

1. Change your class name. It should be in camel-case
2. Try to call pack() instead of setSize() as it will handle it automatically. When I replaced your setSize() with pack(), it was showing a awkward looking GUI which proves your layout and adding elements were not proper.

   ```
       Font size30 = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 30);

       JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
       pnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnl,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

       Container contentPane = getContentPane();

       //--- User Info ---//

       JPanel userInfo = new JPanel();

       JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
       JTextField userField = new JTextField(12);
       userInfo.add(userLabel);
       userInfo.add(userField);

       JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
       JTextField passField = new JTextField(10);
       userInfo.add(passLabel);
       userInfo.add(passField);

       JLabel serverLabel = new JLabel("Mail Server: ");
       JTextField serverField = new JTextField(10);
       userInfo.add(serverLabel);
       userInfo.add(serverField);

       JLabel portLabel = new JLabel("Server Port: ");
       JTextField portField = new JTextField(3);
       userInfo.add(portLabel);
       userInfo.add(portField);

       //--- To: CC: and Subject Fields ---//

       JPanel msgInfo = new JPanel();

       JLabel toLabel = new JLabel("To: ");
       JTextField toField = new JTextField(30);
       msgInfo.add(toLabel);
       msgInfo.add(toField);

       JLabel subLabel = new JLabel("Subject: ");
       JTextField subField = new JTextField(30);
       msgInfo.add(subLabel);
       msgInfo.add(subField);

       //--- Body ---//

       JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel("Body");
       bodyLabel.setFont(size30);

       JTextArea bodyField = new JTextArea(30,70);
       bodyField.setLineWrap(true);
       bodyField.setWrapStyleWord(true);

       JScrollPane bodyScroll = new JScrollPane(bodyField);

       bodyScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
       bodyScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


       pnl.add(userInfo);
       pnl.add(msgInfo);
       pnl.add(bodyLabel);
       pnl.add(bodyScroll);

       contentPane.add(pnl);

       setVisible(true);
       pack();
   ```